# txt file parsing in python with sspecyfic conditions

Tags: python

I am trying to do following:

1. load a .txt file
2. go line by line and change a specyfic word to numbers
3. sort the lines in order to the converted number
4. display the original lines

   ```
    def convert(word):
        if word == "data3": 
            return "1"
        elif word == "data1":
            return "2"
        elif word == "data4":
            return "3"
        elif word == "data3":
            return "4"
   with open("file.txt", "r") as f:
            for num, line in enumerate(f.readlines(), 1): 
                for word in line.split():
                    convert(word)
                    sorted(word)
                    print(line)
   ```

It actually makes something, but I don't see any order it what it makes.
My .txt file looks like this:

```
ABC    ABC   ABC    Data1   ABC
ABC    ABC   ABC    Data3   ABC
ABC    ABC   ABC    Data2   ABC
ABC    ABC   ABC    Data2   ABC
ABC    ABC   ABC    Data3   ABC
```

and I willing to make from it: all datas3, then datas1, then datas2 and then datas4

```
ABC    ABC   ABC    Data3   ABC
ABC    ABC   ABC    Data3   ABC
ABC    ABC   ABC    Data1   ABC
ABC    ABC   ABC    Data2   ABC
ABC    ABC   ABC    Data2   ABC
```

Comment: So you want to sort all the lines, not _each line_. That will require more code. Is the "Data" always in column 4 (index 3)?  Will edit [my answer later](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69628388/1431750), have to step out now. And your checks use "dataN" instead of "DataN" (lowercase vs uppercase 'D').

Comment: Oh, right. Yes I want to sort the whole file in order to this column.

Answer (score -1):

1. Your `convert` function doesn't *`return`* any value. Assigning a new value to the `word` param won't change the original.

```py
def convert(word):
    if word == "data3": 
        return "1"
    if word == "data1":
        return  "2"
    if word == "data4":
        return "3"
    if word == "data3":
        return "4"
    return word  # return original if no match
```

Or better, since you're replacing based on full matches on each word with equality `==` checks, put each search word and its replacement as key-value pairs in a dictionary. Then use [`dict.get()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#dict.get) to lookup that word, and if it's not found, return a default of the original word.

```py
def convert(word):
    return {
        "data3": "1",
        "data1": "2",
        "data4": "3",
        "data2": "4"  # your `data3` repeats in the checks
                      # so this is probably `data2`
    }.get(word.lower(), word)  # "Data1" vs "data1"
```

2. You're putting `sorted(word)` in its own loop so that would just sort the letters in the word. Also, sorted *returns* the elements sorted, it doesn't do an in-place sort. So you'd have to do `new_word = sorted(convert(word))`. <strike>I'm not sure what *"sort the lines in order to the converted number"* means since a line can contain more than one matching word. (You haven't posted a sample of your `file.txt` file or the expected output.) Do you want each line sorted based on its words or</strike> **do you want all the lines sorted?** (Yes)

3. To get all the lines sorted, use the [`sorted()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#sorted) function with the `key` parameter (a function) which `sorted` uses to determine order. We'll pass this function (`convert`) the 4th word in each line (index 3) - the words which we get by splitting.

```py
with open("file.txt", "r") as f:
    lines = f.readlines()  # read all the lines

# print original lines
print(lines)
# or
# print('\n'.join(lines))
# or
# for line in lines:
#     print(line)
# same applies below

sorted_lines = sorted(lines, key=lambda words: convert(words.split()[3]))
# print sorted lines
print(sorted_lines)
```

Output:

```
['ABC    ABC   ABC    Data3   ABC',
 'ABC    ABC   ABC    Data3   ABC',
 'ABC    ABC   ABC    Data1   ABC',
 'ABC    ABC   ABC    Data2   ABC',
 'ABC    ABC   ABC    Data2   ABC']
```

Comment: I mean, that I try to put the data column in nonalphabetic order, so I convert the data into numbers to add them some hierarchy. But the final lines I want to display should be with 'data' not the numbers

Comment: In your code i get an error: TypeError: '<' not supported between instances of 'NoneType' and 'NoneType'

Comment: I think you're using the old version of your code which returns `None`. My `convert()` function returns a string in all circumstances. Check if you copy-pasted it correctly.

Comment: @poiqwlf See the updated answer which sorts all lines on the 4th column.